# Semver policy to exclude offending versions

Tags: npm, package.json, semantic-versioning

Consider a package with running versions:

- `1.0.0`
- `1.0.1`
- `1.0.2`

given the semver policy `~1.0.0` - we'll get the latest patch - and life is great.

Now consider that version `1.0.3` has landed and is an ***offending*** version, so we expect `1.0.4` to correct the offense.

I don't want to wait for the authors to depricate `1.0.3`, and it's anyway on my builder cache. I hope to handle this using the semver policy.

Is there a way I can phrase my semver policy to exclude that offending version, so that until a fix is released I'll get `1.0.2`, and after its released I'll get `1.0.4`?

And - if `1.0.4` is also offending, what will be the way to exclude both `1.0.3` and `1.0.4` so I'll get `1.0.5` as soon as it's published?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah.. found it. I was looking in the wrong place for that...

The way to do that is:

```
 "dependencies": {
   "the-package" : "~1.0.0 < 1.0.3 || ~1.0.4",
```

and if `1.0.4` is found offensive, then

```
   "the-package" : "~1.0 < 1.0.3 || ~1.0.5",
```

It works with `^` as well, if you like, not just `~`.

I expected to find it on the https://semver.org site, but the examples are found with an interactive playground here:

- https://semver.npmjs.com/#syntax-examples